# Can giving all your money to a private company be challenged in court?

Tags: wills

Can giving all your money to a private company be challenged in court? I am wondering if such a will can be challenged using the insanity clause, because it seems like it's not something a lot of people would do.

Comment: The grounds for challenging a will vary by jurisdiction. This means by country, and in federal countries such as Canada, the US, or India, the state or province. Lack of a "sound mind" is often a valid ground, as is "undue influence". The evidence needed would vary. It would be wise to consult a local lawyer.

Comment: Also, the rules would differ depending on whether you are dead or alive. I assume you specifically mean "willing" you property, and that this isn't a run-around of the need to pay taxes and other debts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A lot of people don’t [BASE jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASE_jumping) - that doesn’t make those who do insane

The chance of successfully challenging a will because one of the bequests was slightly odd is essentially zero.